# Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid. on aws lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm trying to setup a Cloudwatch Scheduled Event and my cron expression seems to be invalid, though I can't figure out why.

My cron expression is:

```
functions:
governorCrone:
 handler: handler.governorCrone
 events:
   - schedule: cron(1 * * * * *)
```

i want to run my cron in every min but i am getting the following error every time whenever i deploy my function on serverless

```
 An error occurred: GovernorCroneEventsRuleSchedule1 - Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid. (Service: AmazonCloudWatchEvents; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: fd4fb03c-0b2e-11e9-bc87-9d783a29b264).
```

please tell me if i did somthing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cron expression you are using is invalid.If you want your cron to run every minute then the correct expression will be as shown below.For more examples refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html).

```
cron(0/1 * * * ? *)
```

Comment: thx it is working now can you please tell me why you put ? on 5th place on cron

Comment: In some implementations, used instead of '*' for leaving either day-of-month or day-of-week blank. Other cron implementations substitute "?" with the start-up time of the cron daemon, so that ? ? * * * * would be updated to 25 8 * * * * if cron started-up on 8:25am, and would run at this time every day until restarted again.

Comment: You can also use "rate(1 minute)" if you want something easier to read and more self documenting

Comment: Actually that is a valid cron expression, now sure about AWS implementation: https://crontab.guru/#1_*_*_*_*
I am struggling as well to make it work